# How to inject EJB with @WebServiceRef from Web-module

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I have a JEE6 application, with an ejb and a web-module, running on a GlassFish 3.1.1
Now I wanted to access a WebService (JAX-WS) by injecting it (as a Session Bean) into several Managed Beans.

```
@Stateless
public class AnyService implements AnyServiceLocal {

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdl/AnyService/Any.wsdl")
    private AnyService service;
    @Override
    public String findLastname(Integer key) {
        Any port = service.getAnyPort();
        AnyPerson sp = port.findAnynumber(key);
        return sp.getLastname();
    }

}
```

When I try to access it:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {

    @EJB
    private AnyServiceLocal any;
    public void findLastname() {
        name = any.findLastname(Integer.valueOf(key));
    }
}
```

I'll get these Exceptions

```
WARNUNG: A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB AnyService method public java.lang.String de.mizui.anytest.ejb.bean.AnyService.findLastname(java.lang.Integer)
javax.ejb.EJBException
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5193)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5091)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4879)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2039)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1990)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:213)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
        at $Proxy430.findLastname(Unknown Source)
        ..blabla..
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:134)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:123)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:144)
        at $Proxy431.findEmployeenumber(Unknown Source)
        at de.mizui.anytest.ejb.bean.AnyService.findLastname(AnyService.java:25)
        ..blabla..
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.jmac.provider.config.PipeHelper.makeFaultResponse(PipeHelper.java:321)
..blabla..
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coordinator.CoordinationManager.lookupOrCreateCoordinator(CoordinationManager.java:175)
    (somewhat shortened..)
```

But when I access the WS directly from within the UserBean, it works.. 
Looking forward to your ideas :)

*yay my first post^^

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceRef.html
did you try

     
    @Addressing
    @WebServiceRef(AnyService.class)
    private AnyService service;

Comment: Causes same exceptions. I have also tried some variations with referencing WebService (Any) and WebServiceClient (AnyService).
@Addressing @WebServiceRef(value=AnyService.class) causes Exceptions: it extends Service but it is only the Client (false NetBeans-generated code?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the solution!
Transactions with Webservices have to be atomic, like dependency injection. But it tries to nest the request into the injection-transaction (hihi this rhymes), so it's not atomic anymore.
You can bypass that for the specific method, with an annotation:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class AnyServices{

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdl/AnyService/Any.wsdl")
    private AnyService service;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public String findLastname(Integer key) {
        Any port = service.getAnyPort();
        AnyPerson sp = port.findAnynumber(key);
        return sp.getLastname();
    }

}
```

<3