# Inject generated beans

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb

Let's i have simply `@Stateless` session bean.  (EJB 3.0)

```
    @Stateless
    public class SomeBeanWS implements ISomeBeanWS {  
    // ...  
    }
```

And I have many WebServices (that are beans also) that have already deployed on the app server.
I have WSDLs of this Services.
I can generate Interfaces if this WebServices in my project using Maven.
Can I inject this Webservieces (beans) to my `SomeBeanWS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you're using NetBeans, it provides a "generate WebService from WSDL" tool.
It helped me accessing external WS from within my ManagedBean (by using `@WebServiceRef` annotation there). Only injecting the WS through a Session Bean doesn't work (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305660)).

Edit says: I've found a solution, follow the link ;)