# Web Service Client in a Stateless Enterprise Bean

Tags: java, web-services, ejb

What is the correct way to implement a stateless EJB 3.1 for invoking a web service. My client works as a Servlet, but I want to move the invocation into a EEJ bean. I have to add username and password in the SOAP header envelop to access the WS, which is working fine.

The service the the servlet is using looks like this;

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "MessageService", targetNamespace = "http://...", wsdlLocation = "...wsdl")
public class MessageService
    extends Service
```

Can I wrap `MessageService` in a Stateless EJB or should the bean itself use `@WebServiceRef` (as in the tutorial) without wrapping the MessageService ?

[Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html#bnayx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Local Service

If the *client* and the *provider* lives in same EAR or WAR on the application server, can be invoked like a *ordinal* EJB. e.g.

```
@WebService
@Stateless
public class CalculatorBean implements Calculator {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

The `CalculatorBean` is threadsafe. All business logic that occurs within the `add` method 
is part of a container-managed transaction and not participate in any global transaction.

Alternatively, the client code can look up in the JNDI namespace.

#### Remote Service

The runtime can inject a service object or a port object into a member variable annotated with `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef`.

```
@WebServiceRef(CalculatorService.class)
private Calculator port;
```

The `CalculatorService` class is annotated with the `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient` annotation (the client of the service), which has a `wsdlLocation` attribute.

---

If you want to wrap the WebService into the EJB, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11357999/870248). For read a discussion about this, see [EJB and Web Services: getting the best of both worlds](http://veithen.github.io/2009/11/15/ejb-and-web-services.html).